# Entity Framework Core - Execute raw sql - Same code for SQL/SQLite

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sqlite, entity-framework-core

I'm currently using two different Connections types, (SQLConnection for normal use and SqliteConnection for integration testing), when inserting new exceptions in my LogService.

Because I don't have access to the database context class I'll have to use raw sql to insert new entities, (I only have the database connectionstring).

When running integration tests I have to use SQLite in memory database because of the entity relations, (SQL does not support this in memory).

```
protected async Task InsertException(DateTime utcNow, LogLevel logLevel, EventId eventId, string state, Exception exception, CategoryAppSettings categoryAppSettings, string caller, string ipAddress, int? userId, int? organisationId, string requestId)
{
    string stackTrace = exception?.StackTrace;

    string query =
        "INSERT INTO [Exception] " +
        "(" +
            "[Created]" +
            ",[EventId]" +
            ",[IpAddress]" +
            ",[LogLevel]" +
            ",[Message]" +
            ",[Source]" +
            ",[StackTrace]" +
            ",[State]" +
            ",[UserId]" +
            ",[OrganisationId]" +
            ",[RequestId]" +
        ")" +
        "VALUES" +
        "(" +
            "@Created" +
            ",@EventId" +
            ",@IpAddress" +
            ",@LogLevel" +
            ",@Message" +
            ",@Source" +
            ",@StackTrace" +
            ",@State" +
            ",@UserId" +
            ",@OrganisationId" +
            ",@RequestId" +
        ")";

    Dictionary<string, object> parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
    {
        { "@Created", utcNow },
        { "@EventId", eventId.ToString() ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
        { "@IpAddress", ipAddress ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
        { "@LogLevel", logLevel.ToString() ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
        { "@Message", exception?.Message ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
        { "@Source", caller ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
        { "@StackTrace", stackTrace?.Trim() ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
        { "@State", state ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
        { "@UserId", userId ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
        { "@OrganisationId", organisationId ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
        { "@RequestId", requestId ?? (object)DBNull.Value },
    };
    try
    {
        if (_hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName == "Test")
        {
            using (SqliteConnection sqlConnection = new SqliteConnection($"Data Source={_logAppSettings.ConnectionStrings.Database};Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared;"))
            {
                using (SqliteCommand sqlCommand = new SqliteCommand(query, sqlConnection))
                {
                    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqliteParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value));
                    }

                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(_logAppSettings.ConnectionStrings.Database))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(query, sqlConnection))
                {
                    foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                    {
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(parameter.Key, parameter.Value));
                    }

                    sqlConnection.Open();

                    await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ExceptionModel exceptionModel = new ExceptionModel()
        {
            StackTrace = ex?.StackTrace,
            Message = ex?.Message,
            InnerException = ex?.InnerException.ToString()
        };

        LogModel log = new LogModel()
        {
            Created = $"{utcNow:yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm}",
            LogLevel = LogLevel.Error.ToString(),
            EventId = LogEvents.Log,
            Source = ex.Source,
            IpAddress = ipAddress,
            UserId = userId,
            OrganisationId = organisationId,
            State = "An unexpected error occured while trying to insert new exception.",
            Exception = exceptionModel,
            RequestId = requestId
        };

        InsertLog(utcNow, log, categoryAppSettings);
    }
}
```

As you can see I'm using two different database types, two different connection types. I really don't like it when you have to customize your code just to make the test greens!

**Is it possible to have one connection type for both databases?**

I've looked at "Entity SQL" but I don't think it's supported in Entity Framework Core and it's abit legacy-ish..

Comment: Might it be possible that `SqlConnection` and `SqliteConnection` have a common base class?

Comment: Why don't you have access to the context-class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's maybe not exactly, what you want , but you can avoid doubling code by using DbConnection instead of SQLConnection.
You can define the DbConnectionType anywhere else like:

```
Type connectionType = _hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName == "Test" ? typeof(SqliteConnection) : typeof(SqlConnection);

// If you switch the Connection String outside too, it should work:
string connectionString = _hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName == "Test" ? $"Data Source={_logAppSettings.ConnectionStrings.Database};Mode=Memory;Cache=Shared;" : _logAppSettings.ConnectionStrings.Database;


        using (DbConnection sqlConnection = Activator.CreateInstance(connectionType, new object[] {connectionString}) as DbConnection)
        {
            using (DbCommand sqlCommand = sqlConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                sqlCommand.CommandText = query;
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                   DbParameter param = sqlCommand.CreateParameter();
                   param.ParameterName= parameter.Key;
                   param.Value=parameter.Value;
                   sqlCommand.Parameters.Add(param );
                }

                sqlConnection.Open();

                await sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();


        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: Type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteConnection' and 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection'

Comment: Yes thank you it's working, but it's as you say.. Not something I want

Comment: Buuut.. I don't believe theres a better solution so I'm going to have to accept this for now

Comment: You could also source out the DbConnectionType and the Connection String for the SQLiteConnection into the appsettings of the TestProject, maybe this is what you want.

Comment: Yes I have it that way now together with dbconnection

Comment: I'll give it another try.

Comment: Did you recognize the changes?